# How to use KoolReport in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Anyone knows how to integrate KoolReport into Codeigniter? I had followed the guideline from https://www.koolreport.com/ by unzipped the folder and pasted into my project folder and created that three files (SalesByCustomer.php, SalesByCustomer.view.php and index.php). But it didn't work. Kindly tell me the steps clearly. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [this instruction](https://www.koolphp.net/forum/threads/163.1/integrate-koolcontrols-in-codeigniter-php-framework.html) for integration Koolreport in Codeigniter.